# php - Creating two image resources and center the first in the second image

Tags: php, php-gd

I'm creating an image resource from a URL and merging it into another image as a frame but it won't be centered.

so please tell me how can i center it

here is my code

```
switch (exif_imagetype ( $CompanyLogo )) {
    case 1: // IMAGETYPE_GIF
        $image = imagecreatefromgif($CompanyLogo);
        break;                            
    case '2': // IMAGETYPE_JPEG
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($CompanyLogo);
        break;                            
    case 3: // IMAGETYPE_PNG
        $image = imagecreatefrompng($CompanyLogo);
        break;                            
    case 6: // IMAGETYPE_BMP
        break;
    case 17: // IMAGETYPE_ICO
        break;                            
}

list($width, $height) = getimagesize($CompanyLogo);
$Ratio = ($width / $height);
$rgb = imagecolorat($image, 0, 0);
$r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
$g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
$b = $rgb & 0xFF;
$img = imagecreatetruecolor($frame_width, $frame_height);

$red = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 0, 0);
imagefill($img, 0, 0, $red);
imagecopymerge($img, $image, 0, 0, ($frame_width / 2) - ($width / 2), ($frame_height / 2) - ($height / 2) , $width, $height, 100);
```

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Center watermark on image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18299002/center-watermark-on-image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was passing x , y of my first image in the wrong parameters

solution is :-

```
imagecopymerge($img, $image, ($frame_width / 2) - ($width / 2), ($frame_height / 2) - ($height / 2) , 0, 0 , $width, $height, 100);
```

instead of :-

```
imagecopymerge($img, $image, 0, 0, ($frame_width / 2) - ($width / 2), ($frame_height / 2) - ($height / 2) , $width, $height, 100);
```

Thanks again.